# How to Install/Use Video.js-HD-Toggle-Plugin-master for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, video.js

i am using videojs plugin for wordpress and i would like to use HD Toggle Plugin. i found it on github [https://github.com/Hussnain1/Video.js-HD-Toggle-Plugin].

my problem are..how do i install it? i already emailed the author but till now he didn't reply back. 
i try insert in  but didn't work.

```
<link href="/HD.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/HD(JavaScript-method).js"></script>
```

can anyone help me here. i am totally newbie. thanks